# Can not display base64 encoded images in an HTML fragment in WinJS app

Tags: iframe, winjs, winrt-async

I'm writing a WinJS app that takes an HTML fragment the user has copied to the clipboard, replaces their

Later, when I go to display the .html, I create an iFrame element (using jQuery $(''), and attempt to source the .html into it, and get the following error

0x800c001c - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to add dynamic content. A script attempted to inject dynamic content, or elements previously modified dynamically, that might be unsafe. For example, using the innerHTML property to add script or malformed HTML will generate this exception. Use the toStaticHTML method to filter dynamic content, or explicitly create elements and attributes with a method such as createElement.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=247104.

I don't get the exception if I don't base64 encoded the images, i.e. leave them intact and can display iframes on the page with the page showing images.

If I take the html after subbing the urls for base64 and run it through toStaticHTML, it removes the src= attribute completely from the  tags.

I know the .html with the encoded pngs is right b/c I can open it in Chrome and it displays fine.

My question is I'm trying to figure out why it strips the src= attributes from the  tags and how to fix it, for instance, creating the iframe without using jquery and some MS voodoo, or a different technique to sanitize the HTML?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? 2+? I thought these issues were addressed in the 2.0+ series of jQuery.

Comment: Using jQuery 2.0.3.  I know a lot of issues where address with jq2, not sure about his one.

Answer (score 0):

So, a solution I discovered (not 100% convinced it the best and am still looking for something a little less M$ specific) is the MS Webview

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182879.aspx#WebView

I use some code like below (where content is the html string with base64 encoded images)

```
        var loadHtmlSuccess = function (content) {
            var webview = document.createElement("x-ms-webview");
            webview.navigateToString(content);
            assetItem.append(webview);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use ***execUnsafeLocalFunction***.  For example:

```
  var target = document.getElementById('targetDIV');
  MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function () { 
       target.innerHTML = content}
  );
```